# loading external TPL file to JST

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm trying to load a .TPL file contents to JST["app/index"].

```
loadTemplates: function(views, callback) {
        var deferreds = [];
        $.each(views, function(index, view) {

                deferreds.push($.get('tpl/' + view + '.html', function(data) {
                    window['JST']["app/index"] = data;

                }, 'html'));
        });
        $.when.apply(null, deferreds).done(callback);
    }
```

Chrome inspector shows that TPL files are being loaded but backbone views couldn't access the JST templates.

Comment: Where did you access the JST templates ?

Comment: backbone view. `template: JST["app/index"]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
loadTemplates: function(views, callback) {
    var deferreds = [];
    $.each(views, function(index, view) {

            deferreds.push($.get('tpl/' + view + '.html', function(data) {
                if (window['JST'] === void 0) {
                    window['JST'] = {};
                }
                window['JST']["app/index"] = data;

            }, 'html'));
    });
    $.when.apply(null, deferreds).done(callback);
}
```